# One example in SICP

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

This is an example in SICP, I enter it but it has an error.

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a)
         (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

This is the error:

> function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a variable

Comment: You get that error when you try to define the function, or when you try to run it? If it's when you try to run it, show what you're typing then.

Comment: It's almost certainly because DrRacket is in Beginner Student Language  (BSL) mode: it treats the code above as a compile-time syntax error because it's assumed the student isn't supposed to use higher order functions yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using DrRacket, you may be running DrRacket under the "Beginner Student Language" mode.  At the introductory CS level, that particular language level mode disables higher-order functions.  [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), on the other hand, assumes a language level that allows higher-order procedures.

Assuming this is the case, you can fix this by adjusting DrRacket so it uses a language level that allows higher-order procedures such as [#lang racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html).

See [Choosing a Language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/choose-language.html): switch DrRacket over to "Use the language declared in the source", and make the top line of your program:

```
#lang racket
```

That should then let you write your function.

---

By the way there is [specialized support for SICP](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/neil/sicp.plt/1/17/planet-docs/sicp/index.html) for DrRacket; if you're going to go through SICP, you probably want to use this.  You can enable this support by changing the top *#lang* line to:

```
#lang planet neil/sicp
```

It'll take a little time the first time you run a program with this, as it automatically installs the support software; subsequent use of the package should be fast.

Comment: Current link for SICP support in DrRacket: http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's a problem with the way you're invoking the procedure. For example, this works fine with the above code:

```
(sum values 1 add1 10)
> 55
```